# Who's know why black area is occured in iOS Simulator Retina 4-inch?

Tags: objective-c

When I test in iOS Simulator Retina 3.5-inch, it is well work.
but when in Retina 4-inch, it is occured black area like following a picture.

I can't know this reason...

Would you give me a some idea?

Following is AppDelegate.h & m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MenuViewCon.h"

@class TestViewCon;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TestViewCon *viewController;

@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[TestViewCon alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[TestViewCon alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Next is TestViewCon.h & m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TestViewCon : UIViewController
@end

#import "TestViewCon.h"    
@implementation TestViewCon {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)] autorelease];
    label.text = @"Retina 4 inch testing";
    [label sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
@end
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you app runs letterboxed.
It seems, that you don't support the iphone 5 within your project.

To do that, you need to add a Default-568h@2x.png Image to your project and set it as the launchimage for the iPhone 5.